# Why is my question faded on the main question list?

Tags: bug

From the moment I posted my (89th) question on History SE, it has appeared like this in the main question list:

[image]

When you click to view, it looks fine. It only appears like this on the main list. I know that downvoted and deleted posts appear faded when you 'look inside', but even these are not faded on the main question list.

I use Google Chrome and the question looks like this on both desktops (Windows XP - yes, I know it's old) and my laptop (Windows 8.1).

Comment: Does it happen when you're logged out?  (Try in a private window.)  Do you ignore any tags?

Comment: @NogShine I only have one favourite tag, and I rarely use it in my questions (i.e. all my previous questions contain tags I don't follow but this is the first time a question of mine has appeared faded). In short, I can't see that this question is remarkable in any way compared to my other 88 questions.

Comment: You have the early-modern tag in your ignored tags list, so it's showing up with ignored styling in question lists.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Just checked when logged out - it looks normal.

Comment: @animuson Not sure how it got there. I don't even know where the ignore list is.Also, I have other questions using the early-modern tag but none of them are faded.

Comment: @animuson OK, just found ignore list and found two tags there, removed them, question now appears normal. Thanks, looks like you've solved my problem. Now I'm wondering how those tags got on my ignore list in the first place, and why other questions I posed using those tags were not faded...(??)